# Removing the white margin around my image

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to put an image at the top of my page, i want this image to cover the whole screen from left to right and be exactly at the top, but every time i do it there is an annoying white border at the left of the image, at the right and at the top. How can i remove that white border? Here is what i tried:

Html:

```
    <head>
        <div>
            <img class="image" src="#image">
        </div>
    </head>
```

CSS:

```
  .image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why your div is in the <head> ?

Comment: Put your `<div>` in the `<body>` element. Also, check out CSS resets.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa because i'll have to add a Title and a box over the image later

Comment: Your Markup must go in the body, the head tag is only for linking ressources etc...

Comment: thanks @ZohirSalakCeNa, i'll correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, And put your div in the `<body>`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img class="image" src="G:\Pics\1.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works perfectly now, thanks!!